# Why can't I find caves?

Tags: dont-starve-together

I'm pretty sure I covered all of my map with my friend but I still can't manage to find caves.

How is that ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After wondering for about a day, we finally found out that there's an option that is not enabled by default in the world creation.

[image: Add Caves option on the World tab in the World Creation menu.]

This option is disabled by default because it requires the host to have 2 worlds (top ground and caves) running at once, which drains a lot of resources.

Comment: *Did you remember to enable caves??* I died.

Comment: @djechlin This is a basic feature in DS. I had no idea I had to activate it :P Working in IT you would expect me to apply the "Have you turned it on and off again ?"...

Comment: If you "turned it on and off again", then it wouldn't work at all :)

Comment: Disclaimer, I haven't played recently.  Previously, this was because when they started working on the caves feature, it runs a separate instance of the game serving just the caves, themselves.  Basically players move between the servers when they enter/leave caves.  It's reasonable to assume that this feature is still optional for performance reasons, if this is still how it works.